# Engine for simple client-server two-player turn-based game with random match-making and online statistics

Tags: ide, game-engine, multiplayer

I would like to create a very simple two-player turn-based multiplayer game. The game mechanics are best described as rock-paper-scissors type of game. Upon match start, player choose their equipment, then the match begins; one attacks, the other defends, they switch sides, and it goes on until one of them runs out of hp. If player doesn't choose his action within turn limit, server makes a random move for him, and if player disconnects for any reason, he should be able to rejoin that and only that game.

I will use client-server architecture. I will need random matchmaking mechanism, though playing with friends option would be OK for start if already implemented in the engine. Online statistics must be implemented at some point.

I know object pascal (Delphi, Lazarus) more or less, but absolutely zero in anything networking-related, and these platforms seem absolutely inadequate for the server; bearable for client but still leave a lot to be desired. I was recommended node.js for server and played with it a bit, learning some javascript along the way, but it seems too complicated. Overall, I'm terrible at improvising when it comes to programming, able to learn complex concepts only on someone's well-documented examples. Graphics and GUI designs are no problem, though.

Please recommend me a game engine / IDE to implement my idea with less hassle, and within reasonable timeframe, given the above-mentioned requirements and background.

Comment: I am a fan of Object Pascal, I think its a great language. but who ever recommend JavaScript was right. this type of game is easily made with some JavaScript and a bit of php. is this a two player game? I made a 3d tic tac toe game in Javascript/php where players took turns, and had to implement a simple way of communication back-and-forth over the network for the players to communicate. if you are interested in going this way I can post some JavaScript code to help you.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is a two-player game. I am definitely interested. Please post the examples of code, it will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I not sure how much JavaScript you know.

but if you know how to write simple games and feel comfortable with JavaScript, 
and all you need is a way to handle multiple player in JavaScript
then you can use a small bit of code I wrote for the network part.
 OK lets start:

To make a game with multiple players over a network.
its very easy with JavaScript + php.

basically the first thing you need is a simple way to communicate over the network with the players.

I'll making it simple by letting people use my code. 
I had to write some code for an HTML5 remake of 3d tic tac toe([www.dominicanvoice.com/caps3d](http://www.dominicanvoice.com/caps3d)).
so you can just reuse the code I had to write.

I wrote two objects ***TNetworkCommand***, and ***TFindPlayers***.
***TNetworkCommand***, sets up basic network communication.
And ***TFindPlayers***, is a bit of code build using ***TNetworkCommunication*** to find another player over the network, so that you can play with.

to use the code in your JavaScript game, just include it:

```
<script src="http://www.dominicanvoice.com/js/communication.php"></script>
```

then you can establish a network connection this way:

```
var comm = new TNetworkCommand('game_name'); // setup a communication with the network
```

and to find another player you do it this way:

```
var player = new TFindPlayers(comm,60); // find a player to play with.
```

then you communicate back and forth, sending each other commands.

```
comm.send(player.player,"MY MOVE","{down:'7',up:'3'}");
```

and to receive data use poll the command, this way:

```
command = comm.receive();
```

the data received is in JSON format.

====================================
object ***TNetworkCommand*** :

```
function TNetworkCommand(App) { // App is an unique game name
  function send(user,command,data);  // send, send data to a specific user
  function broadcast(command,data); // broadcast, sends data to all the users
  function receive(); // receive, gets data sent to you from other users
  function save(variable,value); // saves, saves data in a variable to be shared by all
  function restore(variable,value); // restore, gets the value of the data saved in variable
}
```

==================================
object ***TFindPlayers*** :

```
function TFindPlayers(comm,timeOut) { // comm = the establish connection, timeout = tie to spend looking for a player.
  var player;                       // player = 'COMPUTER', if no player was found, or it returns an unique string, identifying the other player.
}
```

================================

not sure if this is what you were looking for this is not an engine,
 just a solution of how to communicate with other players over the internet using JavaScript.
Also, the ***TNetworkCommand***'s save & restore functions also solve the issue of saving the games high score, etc.